# How to put php tag in background url?

Tags: php, html, background

I have code like this ;

```
$Photo = filtering($row['FileIcon128']);

<div class="image" style="background:url(/images/imgs/<?php echo $Photo ?>)"></div>
```

I tried everything

```
 filtering($row['FileIcon128']); , echo ''.$Photo.'';
```

instead of

```
 $Photo
```

But i cant get picture. Any idea?

By the way, i have to use

```
<div class="image"
```

Comment: Give us more code please. Maybe you have a mistake in your SQL-request and handler.

Comment: Are you closing your `php` before starting `<div class="image"...`

Comment: No no, i can get picture with <img src=> but i cant get with background:url

Comment: What exactly is filtering() doing?

Comment: Problem solved, following reply. Thank you guys.

Comment: @Dtractus I edited the answer to explain the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
<?php
$Photo = filtering($row['FileIcon128']);
$string = "/images/imgs/" . $Photo;
?>
<div class="image" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $string; ?>')"></div>
```

---

### Explanation

I saw 3 possible bugs in your code, which were:

1) `<?php echo $Photo ?>` without a semicolon after `$Photo`. I don't know if that's a syntax error or not in inline php, however I added the semicolon to make sure and concatenated the static string with the dynamic variable to make for a less messy inline PHP like this: `<?php echo $string; ?>`.

2) `background:url()` is not the right way to do this. You want to be as explicit as you can, so `background-image:url()`.

3) `background-image:url()` without '' (apostrophes) surrounding the parameter passed. `background-image:url('')` fixed that. I just echoed the code in between the two apostrophes.

Comment: Right! Thank you :) I'll accept you reply 7 min later, Again thanks :)